# error apache any after 5 seconds

Tags: apache-2.2

My apache server (redHat) stops every 5 seconds

I tried to restart apache, reboot server...
When I restart the server, I got this error 5 seconds.
Everything seems ok: cpu usage is 0%, server does not seem to be busy.

```
[Sat Mar 30 02:29:38 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Mar 30 02:29:39 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sat Mar 30 02:29:39 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/local/apache/bin/suexec)
[Sat Mar 30 02:29:39 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.20 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.20 OpenSSL/0.9.8o configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Mar 30 02:29:48 2013] [error] [client 81.56.142.231] File does not exist: /home/proxymis/www/undefined, referer: http://www.proxymismultimedia.com/?fb_action_ids=4859960618908&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=other_multiline&action_object_map=%7B%224859960618908%22%3A339307496159862%7D&action_type_map=%7B%224859960618908%22%3A%22og.likes%22%7D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D
[Sat Mar 30 02:29:49 2013] [error] server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting
```

I also edit **httpd.conf** trying to modify **MaxClients**, **KeepAlive** etc... with no sucess

Any idea ?

extract of **httpd.conf** file

```
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
TimeOut 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive on

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#

##
## Server-Pool Size Regulation (MPM specific)
## 

# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers         5
MinSpareServers      5
MaxSpareServers     10
MaxClients         150
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         2
MaxClients         150
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75 
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>

# perchild MPM
# NumServers: constant number of server processes
# StartThreads: initial number of worker threads in each server process
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxThreadsPerChild: maximum number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of connections per server process
<IfModule perchild.c>
NumServers           5
StartThreads         5
MinSpareThreads      5
MaxSpareThreads     10
MaxThreadsPerChild  20
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>

# WinNT MPM
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in the server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum  number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_winnt.c>
ThreadsPerChild 250
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>

# BeOS MPM
# StartThreads: how many threads do we initially spawn?
# MaxClients:   max number of threads we can have (1 thread == 1 client)
# MaxRequestsPerThread: maximum number of requests each thread will process
<IfModule beos.c>
StartThreads               10
MaxClients                 50
MaxRequestsPerThread       10000
</IfModule>    

# NetWare MPM
# ThreadStackSize: Stack size allocated for each worker thread
# StartThreads: Number of worker threads launched at server startup
# MinSpareThreads: Minimum number of idle threads, to handle request spikes
# MaxSpareThreads: Maximum number of idle threads
# MaxThreads: Maximum number of worker threads alive at the same time
# MaxRequestsPerChild: Maximum  number of requests a thread serves. It is 
#                      recommended that the default value of 0 be set for this
#                      directive on NetWare.  This will allow the thread to 
#                      continue to service requests indefinitely.                          
<IfModule mpm_netware.c>
ThreadStackSize      65536
StartThreads           250
MinSpareThreads         25
MaxSpareThreads        250
MaxThreads            1000
MaxRequestsPerChild      0
MaxMemFree             100
</IfModule>

# OS/2 MPM
# StartServers: Number of server processes to maintain
# MinSpareThreads: Minimum number of idle threads per process, 
#                  to handle request spikes
# MaxSpareThreads: Maximum number of idle threads per process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: Maximum number of connections per server process
<IfModule mpmt_os2.c>
StartServers           2
MinSpareThreads        5
MaxSpareThreads       10
MaxRequestsPerChild    0
</IfModule>

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses (0.0.0.0)
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80

Listen *:80
```

Comment: So what _are_ your settings?

Comment: What is [Sat Mar 30 02:29:48 2013] [error] [client 81.56.142.231] File does not exist: /home/proxymis/www/undefined, referer: http://www.proxymismultimedia.com/?fb_action_ids=4859960618908&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=other_multiline&action_object_map=%7B%224859960618908%22%3A339307496159862%7D&action_type_map=%7B%224859960618908%22%3A%22og.likes%22%7D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D

Comment: Are you sure that your website or another feeding into it is not the problem?  You are obviously exceeding the 150 maxusers within 5 seconds of your website coming up.  Change that value to something like 500.